# Почему поля имееюют не те id (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.
Сегодня столкнулся с интерестным моментом: есть некая таблица какой - то сущности.
В ней поля `id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, `name`. Перед этим создал две записи в ней, но увидев, что по ошибке написал не то, удалил их с помощью `TRUNCATE`. `SELECT` таблицы показал, что она пуста. Но после ввода новых двух записей, они получили `id` `3, 4`. Я так понимаю, проблема с оставшимися индексами, или нет, что тогда делать? Раньше думал при удалении / обновлении записей и соответственно будет обновляться и `id` в этом и суть автоинкремента.
Или это баг, версия клиента `4.1.22-community-nt`.

Comment: нет. счетчики нигде себя так не ведут и это хорошо. конечно, если захотеть можно счетчик "скрутить", но это нештатное поведение для него

Comment: так как это исправит, кроме того как удалить БД.

Comment: А зачем это исправлять ? система должна быть построена так, что бы конкретное значение id не имело никакого значения

Comment: а зачем это исправлять?

Comment: А суть автоинкремента только в том, что бы гарантированно выдать для очередного id уникальное значение. а какое конкретно оно будет не имеет никакого значения

Comment: ладно спасибо за ответы